# can not find eth0 when first boot machine, it's ok when reboot the system, help!

Tags: networking

some commad's results are following:

```
spci -k|grep -i -A2 net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8P67 Deluxe Motherboard
Kernel modules: e1000e

ifconfig -a
lo Link encap:本地环回 
inet 地址:127.0.0.1 掩码:255.0.0.0
inet6 地址: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 跃点数:1
接收数据包:32 错误:0 丢弃:0 过载:0 帧数:0
发送数据包:32 错误:0 丢弃:0 过载:0 载波:0
碰撞:0 发送队列长度:0 
接收字节:2624 (2.6 KB) 发送字节:2624 (2.6 KB)

lsmod | grep e1000e
e1000e 156693 0 

cat /etc/network/interfaces 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

ps : the motherboard is ASUS SABERTOOTH X79, and the update the nework adapter does not work!

thanks

Translated:

```
Local loopback
    inet addr: 127.0.0.1 Mask: 255.0.0.0
    inet6 addr ::: 1/128 Scope: Host
    UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric: 1
    RX packets: 32 errors: 0 dropped: 0 overruns: 0 frame: 0
    TX packets: 32 errors: 0 dropped: 0 overruns: 0 carrier: 0
    Collisions: 0 send queue length: 0
    Received bytes: 2624 (2.6 KB) sent bytes: 2624 (2.6 KB)


grep -i "network" syslog | less
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm kernel: [    2.247188] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 1.5.1-k
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm kernel: [    3.849703] type=1400 audit(1363174975.359:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1034 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]: <info> NetworkManager (version 0.9.4.0) is starting...
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]: <info> Read config file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]: <info> DNS: loaded plugin dnsmasq
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: init!
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: update_system_hostname
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]:    SCPluginIfupdown: management mode: managed
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: end _init.
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]: <info> Loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]: <info> Loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2010 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (8946480) ... get_connections.
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (8946480) connections count: 0
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]: <info> modem-manager is now available
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]: <info> monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]: <info> WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]: <info> WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]: <info> WiMAX enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm NetworkManager[1661]: <info> Networking is enabled by state file
Mar 13 19:42:55 zenm kernel: [    4.325495] type=1400 audit(1363174975.835:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1872
 comm="apparmor_parse

zenk@zenm:/var/log$ dmesg | grep e100
[    0.000000] EFI: mem102: type=4, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000c0346000-0x00000000c03e1000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem103: type=7, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000c03e1000-0x00000000c03e4000) (0MB)
[    2.247188] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 1.5.1-k
[    2.247190] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2011 Intel Corporation.
[    2.247212] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[    2.247220] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    2.247312] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 91 for MSI/MSI-X
[    3.292921] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: PCI INT A disabled
[    3.292926] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -3
```

file:/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rule content followed:

```
   # This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x8086:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0 (e1000e)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="10:bf:48:e3:94:54", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

thx!!!

Comment: Just a hint. Please, have a look on the **/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules** file. It contains the network devices bindings between they're location on the bus, MAC addresses and the names used by **udev**.

Comment: When you boot and it doesn't work, is e1000e loaded in lsmod? Are there any clues here when it isn't working? dmesg | grep e100

Comment: @chili555 i havd commit the syslog information and output of dmesg,any message need let me know, tks

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure this is the problem:

```
e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -3
```

Let's try a driver parameter:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/e1000e.conf
```

A new empty file will open. Add one line:

```
options e1000e eeprom_bad_csum_allow=1
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. Reboot and check again:

```
dmesg | grep e1000e
```

Is the error gone? Worse? Does the ethernet workand connect?